# radio-inline should apply only on col-lg-*, col-md-*, col-sm-* but, not on col-xs-*

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a requirement where the radio buttons should stack vertically on col-xs-* view and should display horizontally on all other (col-lg-*, col-md-* and col-sm-*) view. At present, I am using radio-inline to display the radio buttons horizontally by default.

Fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/Vimalan/hh9qtbfj/

Code:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 control-label">View</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
             <label class="radio-inline">
                 <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" value="Record / Category" />
                 Record / Category
             </label>
             <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" value="Batch" />
                  Batch
             </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Question:

How the 'radio-inline' css class be applied only during col-lg-*, col-md-*, col-sm-* (widths based on media query) but, not on col-xs-*?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to apply a few different styles to override the `.radio-inline` styles.  Apply them in a media query that matches the Bootstrap `xs` size, like so:

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/hh9qtbfj/1/)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .radio-inline {
    display: block;
  }

  .radio-inline + .radio-inline {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

**Note:** These styles need to load *after the bootstrap stylesheet*, otherwise they won't override!

Answer (score 0):

**solution 1:**

```
@media (max-width: 768px) /* >= 768px (small tablet) */
{

 .radio-inline
{
// override the default value
}
}
```

**solution 2:**

```
<label class="foo-class">
   <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" value="Record / Category" />
       Record / Category
</label>

@media (max-width: 768px) /* >= 768px (small tablet) */
{

 .foo-class
 {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     padding-left: 20px;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     font-weight: 400;
     vertical-align: middle;
     cursor: pointer;
 }
}
```

Comment: You using LESS variables in there? Not sure OP included LESS.  Also, that's the `md` size, not the `xs` size.  Lastly, a comment to `override the default value` is not useful.  What are the styles that need to be overridden?